# Git post-receive not running on windows

Tags: windows, git

I'm trying to get a push-to-deploy workflow running with git on our local network. To get started I created the following repositories on my local machine (Windows 7):

- D:/gitTest/remote/test-01.git (bare repository)
- D:/gitTest/local/test-01 (working repository)

When I push to the remote repository I want it to deploy into the folder:

- D:/gitTest/remote/test-01_live

Push and pull between the local and the remote repository work fine and a local pre-push hook (just an echo) gets called.

But the **post-receive** hook in the remote repository is not running.

The file *test-01.git/hooks/post-recieve* contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Script started"
git --work-tree=/d/gitTest/remote/test-01_live --git-dir=/d/gitTest/remote/test-01.git checkout -f
echo "Script ended"
```

If I run the file manually via the git bash it works fine. Also tried (with the same result):

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/d/gitTest/remote/test-01_live git checkout -f
```

Is the post-receive hook triggered if I push to a bare repository on a local machine? Or do the so-called "server hooks" actually need a git server?
Any other ideas why the hook is not triggered?

Cheers!

Comment: _"test-01.git/hooks/post-recieve"_ - this is just a typo in your post, not in the actual filename? It should be __post-receive__, not post_recieve.

Comment: Also, does Windows have something like an executable bit? So you need to `chmod +x` the hook?

Comment: No, as far as i know Windows has no executable bit like unix.
Tried chmod anyway, but no difference.

Comment: The name must be **post-receive** - you have the letters i and e in the wrong order.

Comment: `i` before `e` except after `c`

Comment: Thanks guys!

Spend hours looking for a solution...facepalm to me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the hook and the file must be `post-receive` not `post-recieve`.